# Log4j Custom Appender throwing ClassNotFoundException initially?

Tags: java, log4j

I have this following log4j.xml file in which I am using a Log4J Custom Appender

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE">
      <param value="${logfile}" name="File" />
      <param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex" />
      <param value="200MB" name="MaxFileSize" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender class="com.ubsc.at.properties.CustomAppender" name="CUSTAPPEN">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%m" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
      </appender>

   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC">
     <param name="Blocking" value="false"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="1000"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CUSTAPPEN" />
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="${logLevel}" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

When the Application is started  I am getting this following exception in my jetty console

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ubsc.at.properties.CustomAppender
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:284)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1001)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.<init>(Slf4jLog.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.<init>(Slf4jLog.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
```

I see the problem is that log4j is initialised before my classes are loaded.

What can be done to avoid this error? Copy the class file inside existing log4j.jar and create a new jar?

Please share your ideas. Is there any way I can set my CustomAppender such a way that load this only for my Application packages?

Comment: Is the jar containing your custom appender in the Jetty lib folder ?

Comment: no its not containing .

Comment: Unless you have good reasons not to put it in the `lib`folder, I would do so. I suspect your log4j configuration is read withing the Jetty parent classloader.

Comment: @BGR yes correct , is there anyway i can avoid that ??

Comment: Is the code you need the appender for, running inside a webapp?

Comment: the issue is that i ma getting this exception at startup only , after sometimes its fine , so its clear that log4j is initialised before my classes are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above, you are running into classloader issues.

It is hard to guess from your stacktrace (more of it would be required) if your are loading slf4J+Log4J from the parent class loader or from the webapp URLClassLoader.

Anyway, if slf4J and log4j are installed in the jetty `/lib` folder (e.g. most likely loaded by the jetty parent classloader) any custom appender should be in a jar in the same `/lib` folder.

Alternatively, here is what you can try (untested):

1. Start with a "standard" log4j configuration file (no custom appender)
2. Get the classes of your custom appender in a jar sitting in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp or have the classes directly available in `WEB-INF/classes`
3. Override the `ìnit` method of your servlet to programmatically load your custom appender on the Log 4j logger. Something like

   `Logger.getLogger( "my.package" ).addAppender( new MyCustomAppender(blah) );`

Anything within your servlet logged against "my.package" should now be directed to your custom appender.

Note: SLF4J does not usually cope well with fiddling around the class loaders.